# Centos SSL Certificate failed

Tags: ssl, centos

Hope someone could help me with this nightmare ...

I try to install i ssl certificat to my localhost but i get an error on my ssl logs :

> [ssl:warn] [pid 1613] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA
>   certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

I checked if my port 443 is open with nmap, here the result :

[image]

All looks good in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf ( i think so )

```
ServerName localhost 

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
```

Here the result when i try to access to https://localhost

[image]

I tried on another machine to configure /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf with the virtualhost on port 443 but i get the same result.

I genereted the certificate with the following tutorial :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7

Thanks a lot in advance !!!!! hope someone could help

Comment: In short: that's what you can expect when using self-signed certificates. Also see the many results of a [simple google search for this string](https://www.google.com/search?q="RSA+server+certificate+is+a+CA+certificate")

Comment: I know but still doesn't work :(

Comment: First, this is no error but a warning ([ssl:warn) which you can ignore. And if anything does not work you did not tell it, you've just shows this warning.

Comment: The problem is that i can't access to https://localhost ! The web is not show. I use virtual box